# Reverse proxy two servers based on subpath

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

apache question. Must be something simple, but I'm failing.

I'm trying to configure apache as a reverse proxy to two servers behind it. The tricky part is that the only difference to register the proxy rule is a subpath.

My idea is:

```
mydomain.com -> localhost:8083
mydomain.com/api -> localhost:8080/api
```

Currently my config is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/

        ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/api #already tried with slashes on both first and second parameters
        ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/api #already tried with slashes on both first and second parameters

</VirtualHost>
```

But the /api isn't working, it keep sending the request to 8083. Any ideas on why?

thanks for the attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing the '/api' ProxyPass+ProxyPassReverse before the '/' one. I strongly suspect '/' is acting as a catchall and you're never getting to the '/api' case. This would explain why you always go to 8083, which is the '/' case.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/api #already tried with slashes on both first and second parameters
        ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/api #already tried with slashes on both first and second parameters

        # do this last...
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/


</VirtualHost>
```